# Why using string instead of char shows error in the following code?

Tags: c++

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string str="ABC";
    int n=strlen(str);
    cout<<n;
}
```

This shows error which is:

```
error: cannot convert ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string}’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘size_t strlen(const char*)’
     int n=strlen(str);
```

But this works fine:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char str[]="ABC";
    int n=strlen(str);
    cout<<n;
}
```

What is the reason behind this?

Comment: I'd recommend to stop guessing and instead get a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). And get rid of some bad habits like [`#inlcude <bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) and [`using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Answer (score 2):

`strlen` is a function that counts the nuber of characters between the memory adress specified by the `const char*` argument and the first `\0`. So you cannot pass a `string` as argument, since it does not represent any memory address. Instead use

```
str.size()
```

or (not efficient also not expected result if the string contains `\0`)

```
strlen(str.c_str()
```

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that `strlen` can work, but _might_ return a different result, because `std::string` is allowed to contain `'\0'` in the middle of the string.

Comment: Yes you're right, I editted the post :) Thanks